# Emitter from MITT npm now receiving emits

Tags: npm, vuejs3, eventemitter

I have an application, consisting of https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7ksM.png

The console does not show me any problems :<

I don't know what to do anymore :/

I would like to pass dynamically changing information

```
data() { return { hash: '', }; },
```

I use the emitter from MITT for this.

Emits information using:

```
emitter.on('update', this.hash)         
console.log('Sending data:', this.hash);
```

Checking if it has been sent console log.
`emit` is called as soon as the value is entered in the hash.

Emit happens in the Landingpage.vue component (image)

Receive emit wants in menu.vue (photo)

I do it using:

```
data() {
    return { hash: "", };
},
mounted() {
    emitter.on('*', (hash) => {
        console.log('Received data:', hash);
    });
},
```

Unfortunately, it does not receive any value in the menu.vue component

My mitt.js file:

```
import mitt from 'mitt';
// Create a new emitter
const emitter = mitt();

// Export that emitter
export default emitter;
```

My `main.js` file:

```
import { createApp, Vue } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router.js';
import emitter from './mitt';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(router);

app.config.globalProperties.$mitt = emitter;

app.mount('#app');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and format your code properly, complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: check the [usage instructions](https://github.com/developit/mitt#usage).  you're not emitting anything, you've actually set up two listeners instead.